# Statistical test for significance for plant growth over time. Is one-way ANOVA test appropriate?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, repeated-measures, biostatistics, growth-model

I conducted an experiment where I had five different conditions and I measured plants growth. There were five trials for each condition. The plant's height was measured 8 times over 23 days. Can I do a one-way ANOVA test for these results? This is what I have tried so far:
One way ANOVA repeated measures. -- I thought repeated measures because each day's average would be paired?
[image]

The numbers I put in for each treatment are the average of the five trials for each condition. They are in order for which day it was. Is this correct?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated! I want to know if this is the right way to do it or if I'm just completely wrong. I want to know if there is a statistically significant relationship between my conditions and plant height.

EDIT: The conditions were different amounts of a substance, so different levels of a continuous variable.

Comment: How best to proceed depends in part on what your 'conditions' were. Were they different levels of some continuous variable or totally different treatments?

Comment: @mkt  different levels of a continuous variable.

Comment: In that case, a regression-based approach probably makes more sense.